# What is a clean way of getting validation loss with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I am  building a distributed tensor-flow model, and I am a little confused about how to use tf.MonitoredTrainingSession in a clean way.

Here is my training code:

```
#Define number of training steps
hooks=[tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=FLAGS.nb_train_step)]

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=target,
    is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
    checkpoint_dir=FLAGS.logs_dir,
    hooks = hooks) as sess:

    while not sess.should_stop():
        batch_train = gen_train.next() #training data generator

        feed_dict = {X: batch_train[0],
                        Y: batch_train[1]}

        variables = [loss, merged_summary, train_step]
        current_loss, summary,  _ = sess.run(variables, feed_dict)
        print("Batch loss: %s" % current_loss)
```

Now if I want to get my model validation loss every `n` training steps, I could just add that block to be evaluated every  `n` steps:

```
batch_val = gen_val.next() #validation data generator
feed_dict = {X: batch_train[0],
            Y: batch_train[1]}

val_loss = sess.run([loss],feed_dict)
```

But that would increment the number of steps in my hook, meaning that the validation loss computations would count as a training step. Is there a clean way to do that? Am I misunderstanding the role of hooks?